# Invalid manifest file Chrome Web Store (crx file can't be updated)

Tags: google-chrome, manifest, chrome-web-store, google-chrome-app

We've recently updated manifest file from Developer Dashboard with exactly the same one (with higher "version").

After that, users, who try to install our app are receiving error "Invalid manifest file".

We've searched any cure through web, we've tried really everything, but nothing works. New manifest file, without zip compression, ANSI encoding, short path of upload folder, different computers with diff OSs, read and write permissions to manifest file. Non of that and a bunch of random reuploads.

What we have:

1. We can install app from a local folder, so we guess we have a valid manifest file
2. Our attempts points that https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Ddcheokfcfjenankgnpcmcoepfnckjpdo%26uc issues old crx file
3. This is our app — https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rotario-free-match3/dcheokfcfjenankgnpcmcoepfnckjpdo

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Rotario Free Match3",
  "description": "Twist the color figures to match 3 in a row",
  "version": "0.2.1.10",
  "icons": { "16": "16_icon.png", "128": "128_icon.png" },
  "permissions": [ "unlimitedStorage", "notifications" ],
  "app": {
    "urls": [ "http://chrome.rotario.me/" ],
    "launch": { "web_url": "http://chrome.rotario.me/" }
  }
}
```

Does anybody know why Google servers haven't already update crx file more than a day?

Comment: At the same visiting https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Ddcheokfcfjenankgnpcmcoepfnckjpdo%26uc through a proxy gives an updated (last version) crx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug we had fixed as of this morning. Try re-uploading your item and re-publishing it. Don't forget to bump up the version number.

Answer (score 0):

This answer worked for me after i updated my extension yesterday.

[Developer Chrome extension: Package is invalid. Details: "Could not uzip extension'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259125/developer-chrome-extension-package-is-invalid-details-could-not-uzip-extensi)

The General idea is that you can no longer package your extension within a folder inside the zip. The manifest.json file must be in the root of the zip.