# Newly updated extensions cannot install

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

***FOUND AN ANSWER*** [Developer Chrome extension: Package is invalid. Details: "Could not uzip extension'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259125/developer-chrome-extension-package-is-invalid-details-could-not-uzip-extensi)

A recent update to Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard has broken some features. Including "User Feedback", but most importantly any newly uploaded zip packages are not downloadable by any user through the web store, nor will they update if the extension is already installed.

I have an active extension which I updated yesterday, but since that update, users have not been able to install the latest version, getting an "cant unzip" message. I'm thinking it could be a problem with the packager.

Is anyone else having this problem, does anyone know a way to resolve it?

I have tried:
Rebuilding the zip and bumping the version number
Rebuilding the manifest.json and utf8 encoding

The extension URL is
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-google-background/jepibmfmhopgkplegmkjgifmhabbjadg

There appears to be other people with the same problem over the last few days here
https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=&nomobile=true#!topic/chromium-extensions/d56BP7CTU-M

Comment: possible duplicate of [Developer Chrome extension: Package is invalid. Details: "Could not uzip extension'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259125/developer-chrome-extension-package-is-invalid-details-could-not-uzip-extensi)